# Ejecutar programa de sockets (cliente-servidor) con una VM de Azure

Tags: java, azure

Tengo un programa que utiliza sockets (en Java) en donde el cliente y el servidor se comunican. De manera resumida, el servidor le pide al cliente un día y el servidor le responde con una recomendación.

Existen dos programas uno para el Server y otro para el cliente. Para ejecutarse el server únicamente necesita el puerto:

```
java serverDay <port>
```

y el del cliente necesita de la IP y del puerto

```
java clientDay <IP> <port>
```

Obviamente en mi ambiente local si funciona, pero Lo quiero llevar a la nube, para eso hice una VM de Azure, le instalé java y ejecuté el programa del servidor. El problema es al momento de ejecutar el programa del cliente, ya que este no puede realizar la conexión. El programa del servidor se ejecuta sin ningún problema.

¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?

Comment: el programa cliente corre en la misma vm o en otra vm en la misma red local?

Comment: el programa cliente corre en otro equipo (en este caso en mi computadora)

Comment: y pregunto de nuevo el otro equipo o vm está en la misma red local?

Comment: Son diferentes redes

Comment: Y allí justo reside el problema, debes crear una red virtual para que se detecten, inténtalo y si tu intento no funciona agrega la información a la pregunta los datos de la VPC que crees, y la salida del comando ping de una máquina a otra ( la VM a tu pc y visceversa )

Comment: pero como puedo conectar mi computadora (o cualquier otra) a la red virtual de la VM? Alguna documentación, video que recomiendes? Por más que busco no encuentro

Comment: Como dato, el comando ping ya lo probé desde mi computadora con la IP publica de la VM y me devuelve todos los paquetes